# MessageBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, messagebox

How do I show a AJAX "Message Box" in GWT? I know I can use the `Window.alert()` function, but that's too ugly/annoying. Is there a built-in function for?

Thank you!

Yvan

Comment: Note that Ajax is not a synonym for dynamic HTML...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is simple implementation of custom alert widget (modify it to what you want):

```
public static DialogBox alertWidget(final String header, final String content) {
        final DialogBox box = new DialogBox();
        final VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        box.setText(header);
        panel.add(new Label(content));
        final Button buttonClose = new Button("Close",new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
                box.hide();
            }
        });
        // few empty labels to make widget larger
        final Label emptyLabel = new Label("");
        emptyLabel.setSize("auto","25px");
        panel.add(emptyLabel);
        panel.add(emptyLabel);
        buttonClose.setWidth("90px");
        panel.add(buttonClose);
        panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(buttonClose, HasAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        box.add(panel);
        return box;
    }
```

And use it like (note center() method at the end, it actually shows the widget):

```
CustomWidgets.alertWidget("Adding account failed",
                "System failed to add this account. Please chceck your settings properly.").center();
```

Comment: btw I am using final keyword like madman, don't bother with that if you don't wanto to :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DialogBox instead.